# Function that generates multiple dynamic ID's with a defined pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a function that generates multiple dynamic ID's with a defined pattern, how do I do that?

followup: [Vue.js: How to generare multiple dynamic ID's with a defined pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49776146/8770366)

**Details:**

I am creating a dynamic school-test application. When the button "Add question" is clicked, a 
div with 4 input fields and 4 radio buttons are generated. Each input and radio button needs to have an ID.
So far, the function generates a value, that I hope can be used as an ID. Every radio button has a 
name, that makes it possible to only choose one option in the group it belongs to. With every button
click on the "Add Question" button (which is a radio button), this particular "name" is used to count button clicks. With the help of the counter, the dynamic ID for the "question" input field and "options" input fields
(that is connected to the radio buttons) is generated in this pattern:

**Example**

*Testtitle-Question-Option*

```
JavaScriptQ1   (Question)
JavaScriptQ1O1 (Option)
JavaScriptQ1O2  
JavaScriptQ1O3
JavaScriptQ1O4
```

Since there is a div that is generated when the test is launched, and the ID is only generated by button clicks one
div won't get it's ID's. It seems that there is only one question in the ID's in the example above when it's in fact two!

I am currently not using saveTest(), which will be used to save the test into a mySQL database, but it may be used to solve this!

**1.** I want that one extra "group of ID's" is generated, so each input field gets an ID, but how do I do that?

**2.** When this matter is solved, how do I generate unique ID's for the radio buttons?

**3.** How do I then do to use the generated values as ID's. How do I "attach" them to their input fields and radio buttons?

**4** Is there any other, better ways to solve this? The ID's has to follow a certain pattern since they will be saved in
a database and then be used to correct the tests.

I know that it's a rather complex issue, but I have tried to explain as good as possible.

I advise that you look at the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/61567/) instead! Click on Add Question and you will see how it works.

```js
var name=1;
$("body").on('click', '#radioAddQuestion', function () {
    var singleQuestionModule = "singleQuestionModule";
    var question = $(".module:first").clone()
        .find("input:text").val("").end();

    var question_label = $(".question-label:first").clone();
    $(question).find(':radio').prop('checked', false);
    $(question_label).insertBefore(".options-label:last");
    $(question).insertBefore(".options-label");
    $(question).find(':radio').attr('name', "n" + name);
// Here is where the ID value is currently generated:
    name++;

    let questionId = theTitle + "Q" + name;
    console.log(questionId);

    for (a = 1; a <= 4; a++) {
        let optionId = theTitle + "Q" + name + "O" + a;
        console.log(optionId);
    }
    console.log(name)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="singleQuestionModule">
    <form class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-group">
            <label id="wQuestionLabel" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;" for="wQuestion">Question:</label>

        </div>
        <!-- The Question Inputfield that needs ID-->
        <div class="input-group input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" id="wQuestion" style="width: 540px;">
            </div>

        <div class="input-group input-group">
            <label id="questionOptions" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;" for="wQuestion">Enter avaible options:</label>
        </div>

        <!-- The radio buttons and option input fields that need ID's-->

        <div class="input-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="radio" name= "q" id="option1" aria-label="">
                      </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="radio" name="q" id="option4" aria-label="">
                      </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
        </div>
        <!-- The Add and Save Test Buttons-->
        <span class="options-label"></span>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-success" id="radioAddQuestion">
                    <input type="radio" @click="counter += 1" name="options" autocomplete="off">Add Question</label>

                <label class="btn btn-success">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="radioSaveTest" value="saveTest()" autocomplete="off">Save Test </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the script. just have look on that. It will generate dynamic ID for all controls that you have been used.

```js
var name=1;
    var theTitle="online";

    $("body").on('click', '#radioAddQuestion', function () {
        name++;     
        $(".dynamicform").append(createQuestion(name));
        
    });


     $(".dynamicform").append(createQuestion(name));
    function createQuestion(name){
     var dynamic=`<span class="module">
                        <legend class="col-form-legend col-sm-10"></legend>
                        <div class="input-group input-group">
                            <label id="wQuestionLabel" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;" for="wQuestion">Question:</label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="input-group input-group">
                             <!-- The Question Inputfield that needs ID-->
                            
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name}" style="width: 540px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="input-group input-group">
                                <label id="questionOptions" class="form-control-label" style="width: 540px;"
                                       for="wQuestion">Enter
                                    avaible options:</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <!-- The radiobuttons and option inputfields that needs ID's-->

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="input-group input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="radio" name="${theTitle +"rg"+name}" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "O" + "1"}" aria-label="">
                      </span>
                                <input type="text" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "input" + "1"}" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="input-group input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="radio" name="${theTitle +"rg"+name}" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "O" + "2"}" aria-label="">
                      </span>
                                <input type="text" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "input" + "2"}" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="input-group input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="radio" name="${theTitle +"rg"+name}" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "O" + "3"}" aria-label="">
                      </span>
                                <input type="text" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "input" + "3"}" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="input-group input-group">
                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <input type="radio" name="${theTitle +"rg"+name}" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "O" + "4"}" aria-label="">
                      </span>
                                <input type="text" id="${theTitle + "Q" + name + "input" + "4"}" class="form-control" aria-label="" style="width: 540px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                    `;
               return dynamic;     

    }
```

```css
#singleQuestionModule {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="singleQuestionModule">
    <form class="form-group">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <fieldset class=" form-group row">
                <div class="dynamicform">
                  <!--Dynamic form comes here-->
                </div>
                <span class="options-label"></span>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-success" id="radioAddQuestion">
                            <input type="radio" @click="counter += 1" name="options" autocomplete="off">Add Question</label>

                        <label class="btn btn-success">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" id="radioSaveTest" value="saveTest()" autocomplete="off">Save
                            Test </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/d9tfk1u6/

Comment: Great solution! You taught me something new today!

Comment: How would you do this in Vue.js @DeepuReghunath? If you want to and have time to do so, I would be happy if you looked into https://stackoverflow.com/q/49776146/8770366!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put a first id on the elements that are already there? If you want to use the first id that comes out of the id generation function, either change the id generation function so it skips that, or use an onload to add it.

This seems like the obvious solution to the problem, so maybe I've misunderstood it.

Comment: The thing is that this test may be used over and over again with different titles. Each ID has to be unique so I can separate it from the others since it will be in a database with many, many other tests. The only reason that the ID you are mentioning is there is to make the frontend function to work.

Comment: @josefdev I assumed that you had a function that generated unique ids. If so, just run it on page load to add unique ids to the starting elements.

Comment: I have a function, but I cant just add it on page load, since I have to be able to bind all id's to the particular test according to a specified pattern to be able to identify it in the database. It has to follow the exact same pattern as all other id's in the code. You can see the example how the pattern is constructed and why it is so. 

But I may be able to have this function where the title of the test is created.., I haven't thought about it before!